# Code for automatic updating Userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'd like to know on how to code a userform (VBA Excel) with automatically updating itself when the cell values has changed.

I have produced a button that will show the userform with labels and text boxes. But whenever i click it yes it shows up but i need to click the userform in order for me to see the values.

Need help.

Thank you in advance,

Tramyer

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet.Change` event is fired everytime you change the contents of a cell on a given worksheet.

You can create an event handler in the worksheet module (usually labeled Sheet1, Sheet2 etc. in the VBA editor) that is called every time the event is fired:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```

This example just outputs the address of the cell that was changed, but you can adapt this to update your userform with the changed values instead.